# SYSTEMD_SERVICE_swupdate value swupdate.service does not exist

Tags: yocto, software-update

I am trying to build `swupdate` image by running `bitbake swupdate-image` but getting following errors,

```
ERROR: swupdate-2019.04-r0 do_package: SYSTEMD_SERVICE_swupdate value swupdate.service does not exist
ERROR: swupdate-2019.04-r0 do_package: 
ERROR: swupdate-2019.04-r0 do_package: Function failed: systemd_populate_packages
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/panther2/warrior/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/swupdate/2019.04-r0/temp/log.do_package.22017
ERROR: Task (/home/panther2/warrior/sources/meta-swupdate/recipes-support/swupdate/swupdate_2019.04.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1'
```

I am building for `warrior` yocto branch. Error indicates that `swupdate.service does not exist` but `swupdate.service` does exist under `meta-swupdate/recipes-support/swupdate/swupdate`. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you use `systemd` as init system?

Comment: Yes. I use `systemd`

Comment: Can you try latest version with `PREFERRED_VERSION_swupdate = "git"` ?

Comment: Should I add into my own layer's `layer.conf` file?

Comment: I have added in my own layer's `layer.conf` now that error is gone but getting another error
`swupdate-git-r0 do_package: QA Issue: swupdate: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
  /usr/lib/libswupdate.a
  /usr/lib/lua/5.3/lua_swupdate.so.0.1
Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install.
swupdate: 2 installed and not shipped files. [installed-vs-shipped]`
Should I post it as a different question?

Comment: Are you using Poky in warrior version too? Can you check `bitbake -e swupdate | grep ^FILES_swupdate-staticdev`, `libswupdate.a` should be included in it. No please keep this question thread.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be included. Here is the output
`FILES_swupdate-staticdev="/usr/lib64/*.a /lib64/*.a /usr/lib64/swupdate/*.a"`

Comment: It seems swupdate doesn't like ${libdir} to be /usr/lib64 instead of /usr/lib, maybe you can add something like `do_install_append(){ mv ${D}/usr/lib/* ${D}${libdir}/ }` ?

Comment: Now it is saying same about `/usr/lib`. Here is the error,
`swupdate-git-r0 do_package: QA Issue: swupdate: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
  /usr/lib
Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install.
swupdate: 1 installed and not shipped files. [installed-vs-shipped]`

Comment: `do_install_append(){ mv ${D}/usr/lib/* ${D}${libdir}/       rmdir ${D}/usr/lib }`

Comment: It worked. Just wow! struggled a lot..Thank you so much.. For this question, you could write an answer suggesting `PREFERRED_VERSION_swupdate = "git"`

Comment: I prefer not to add this workaround as an answer, I'm not sure why 2019.4 does not work

Comment: Sounds good....

Answer (score 0):

swupdate-image is a rescue system - it generates a Ramdisk. Care was taken about footprint - it runs then with SystemV and not with systemd. If you want to buid swupdate-image with systemd as init, add your own swupdate-image.bbappend and rearrange the list of packages.

Comment: Do you have more information on this? Can you provide a sample?